# asp.net core 8 razorpage InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

i have a category model , category reository and one controller with  simple view

but i got an error "InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MvcCRUD.Models.Category]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'MvcCRUD.Models.Category'.
"

the error told me ,I passed category not list , but in my code you can see it's not true

also this my code

my view

```
@using MvcCRUD.Models;
@model List<Category>

@section title {Page}

<h3>Categories Page</h3>

<p>Simple Categories Page</p>

<ul>
    @foreach (var category in Model)
    {
        <li><a href="/categories/edit/@category.CategoryID">@category.Name</a></li>
    }
</ul>
```

and my controller

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var cate = CategoryRepository.GetCategories(); // return List<Category>
    return View("Index", cate);
}
```

Category Repository

```
public static class CategoryRepository
{
    private static List<Category> _categories = new List<Category>()
    {
        new Category {CategoryID = 1,Name = "Foods",Description = "it is food category"},
        new Category {CategoryID = 1,Name = "Drink",Description = "it is drink category"}  ,
        new Category {CategoryID = 1,Name = "Meat",Description = "it is meat category"} ,
    };
    public static List<Category> GetCategories()
    {
        return _categories;
    }
}
```

and last one my model category

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;


}
```

this is my Practice and first try also I used the ICollection , IEnumerable ... but nothings is changed

Comment: The error mrssage says the opposite of your interpretation. It wants you to pass a single category.

Comment: I remove"@section title {Page}" and  test your code and don't meet the error like yours.  like:https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YLka.png What's your @section title {Page} ?